# How to separate ssh sessions with remote geth node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I try to connect with my remote node for using geth. The safe interaction is provided with SSH-protocol. 
My app can maintain stream of data between client and server (node), however when geth is doing synchronization (after the launch e.g.) it sends a lot of (needless) information about the process of sync (downloading blocks etc.) 
Does it exist any approach to  separate ssh sessions, so as to one of these respond to my geth commands only without any information about sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can run your remote node with a lower level of logging.

example

```
geth --verbosity 0
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), particularly

```
LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS:
  --verbosity value         Logging verbosity: 0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=core, 5=debug, 6=detail (default: 3)
  --vmodule value           Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of <pattern>=<level> (e.g. eth/*=6,p2p=5)
```

- You can create another ssh session, and attach to the console

with

```
geth attach
```

That way you can introduce commands, without the burden of the logging.